# Architecture of lamellae in trabeculae in spongy bone

Tags: bone-biology, bone

It is easy to find the architecture of lamellae in osteons in compact bone, they're layers of collagen fibers and each layer alternates in the angle the fibers are oriented. Is the lamellae in trabeculae similar, and the main difference that there isn't a central blood vessel to supply the bone cells with nutrients, since that is done trough the marrow instead?